# Linear SVM feature weights interpretation. Binary classification, only positive feature values

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-selection, regression-coefficients, scikit-learn

I'm using `clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')` on a data set with only two classes $y \in \{-1, +1\}$ and the feature values of all samples are normalized between 0 and 1. We know from various studies ([Guyon et al. 2003](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/guyon03a/guyon03a.pdf), [Chang et al. 2008](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v3/chang08a/chang08a.pdf)) that the magnitude of a feature weight in `clf.coef_` is indicative of the importance of the feature for the classification.

*My question is how the sign (positive or negative) of the feature weight can be interpreted, when all the features values are positive?*

Given that all my feature values are normalized between 0 and 1, I think that a negative feature weight contributes to a negative classification ($y=-1$), while a positive feature weight contributes to a positive classification ($y=+1$). `clf.coef_` is the coefficients in the primal problem. Looking at the formulation of a hard-margin primal optimization problem, using a linear kernel:

$$
\text{Minimize } \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{w} \\
\text{Subject to } y_i (\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_i - b) \geq 1, \quad i = 1, \ldots, N
$$

where $y_i \in \{-1, +1\}$ is the class of sample $i$, $\mathbf{x}_i$ is the feature representation of sample $i$ and $\mathbf{w}$ is the feature weights, which I presume is what `clf.coef_` returns. $b$ is just an offset of the max-margin hyperplane. From the constraint $y_i (\mathbf{w}\mathbf{x}_i - b) \geq 1$, we can thus see that

- If $y_i = -1$

  - Then the dot product $\mathbf{w}\mathbf{x}_i$ has to be negative. Since all feature values in $\mathbf{x}$ are positive, then a negative feature weight contributes to a negative classification.
- If $y_i = +1$

  - Then the dot product $\mathbf{w}\mathbf{x}_i$ has to be positive. Similarly, a positive feature weight then contributes to a positive classification.

A similar analysis can made for the soft-margin case.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any academic sources for this interpretation of the sign of the feature weights. Perhaps the case of a binary classification with only positive features isn't general enough to deserve a study. My questions are thus:

- Is my analysis and subsequent conclusion correct, that a negative feature weight contributes to a negative classification, and a positive feature weight contributes to a positive classification?
- Does anyone know of any academic sources that I can cite to strengthen my claim?

A comment in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/39311/99516) seems to support my claim, but no motivation or references are provided.

---

## Update

I implemented some code to test my hypothesis. Using 9 features such that

- features 1, 2, 3 occur more frequently in the negative class
- features 4, 5, 6 occur as frequently in both classes
- features 5, 6, 7 occur more frequently in the positive class

Code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm

N = 1000  # number of samples
n_features = 9
n_iter = 100

# features 1, 2, 3 occur more in the negative class
# features 4, 5, 6 occur as frequently in both classes
# features 7, 8, 9 occur more frequently in the positve class
mean_neg = [0.90, 0.80, 0.70, 0.20, 0.50, 0.70, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05]
mean_pos = [0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.20, 0.50, 0.70, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90]
cov = np.eye(n_features)*0.04  # std = 0.2 <=> var = std**2 = 0.04

weights_avg = np.zeros(n_features)
accuracy_avg = 0

for _ in range(n_iter):
    # generate data
    X_neg = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_neg, cov, N//2)
    X_pos = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_pos, cov, N//2)
    # only values between 0 and 1
    X_neg[X_neg < 0] = 0
    X_neg[X_neg > 1] = 1
    X_pos[X_pos < 0] = 0
    X_pos[X_pos > 1] = 1

    X = np.concatenate((X_neg, X_pos), axis=0)  # training data
    y = np.ones(N)  # labels
    y[:N//2] = -1  # first N/2 samples are from the negative class

    clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
    clf.fit(X, y)
    # testing on training data, just to see if the SVM learns
    y_pred = clf.predict(X)

    accuracy_avg += np.sum(y_pred==y) / N
    weights_avg += clf.coef_[0]  # coef_ has shape [n_class-1, n_features]

accuracy_avg /= n_iter
weights_avg /= n_iter

print("Average accuracy on training data: {}".format(accuracy_avg))
print("Average linear SVM weights:")
print(weights_avg)
```

Running this gave the following output

```
Average accuracy: 0.99999
Average linear SVM weights:
[-1.3517 -1.0827 -0.7347  0.0058  0.0237 -0.0354  0.7371  1.0735  1.3423]
```

And we see that the sign of the feature weight indeed is indicative of which class a feature contributes to, and that the magnitude also tells us how informative the feature is for the classification!

Answer (score 2):

My answer may be trivial - I thought the parameter sign indicated whether the point was above or below the hyperplane. [Slide 4 of these lecture notes](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/ml/lect2.pdf) show this (I think). Here is the relevant slide:

[image]

Citation: Zisserman, A., "Lecture 2: The SVM classifier", C19 Machine Learning lectures Hilary 2015, Oxford University, Oxford, (accessed 15/8/2017)

Comment: We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of link-only answers, due to linkrot. Can you post a full citation & a summary of the information at the link, in case it goes dead?

Comment: I've added an image of the relevant slide and cited the material appropriately. I hope this helps!