# what is weight vector and bias in svm

Tags: svm, weighted-sampling

I'm trying to understand the SVM algorithm but not able to understand what weight vector and bias is ? Could anyone explain it in laymen terms.

Comment: This video helped me once to fully and thoroughly understand SVMs  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PwhiWxHK8o (Yet no explanation of weight vector and bias, just great explanation of the whole concept)

Comment: for weights: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/39243/how-does-one-interpret-svm-feature-weights