# Which search range for determining SVM optimal C and gamma parameters?

Tags: classification, svm, kernel-trick

I am using SVM for classification and I am trying to determine the optimal parameters for linear and RBF kernels. For the linear kernel I use cross-validated parameter selection to determine C and for the RBF kernel I use grid search to determine C and gamma.

I have 20 (numeric) features and 70 training examples that should be classified into 7 classes.

Which search range should I use for determining the optimal values for the C and gamma parameters?

Answer (score 39):

Check out [A practical guide to SVM Classification](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=libsvm%20parameter%20search%20filetype%3apdf&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf&ei=6bAuUrqCIoKn0AWI7IDwDg&usg=AFQjCNFol0McRktHC6gsBxKXqQMvmQUFeg&sig2=B_UX_55hQoHLm3rsCKUInw&bvm=bv.51773540,d.bGE) for some pointers, particularly page 5.

> We recommend a "grid-search" on $C$ and $\gamma$ using cross-validation. Various pairs of $(C,\gamma)$ values are tried and the one with the best cross-validation accuracy is
>   picked. We found that trying exponentially growing sequences of $C$ and $\gamma$ is a
>   practical method to identify good parameters (for example, $C = 2^{-5},2^{-3},\ldots,2^{15};\gamma = 2^{-15},2^{-13},\ldots,2^{3}$).

Remember to normalize your data first and if you can, gather more data because from the looks of it, your problem might be heavily underdetermined.

Comment: Should peer testing be done manually? there is not a library to achieve it?

Answer (score 13):

Check out section 2.3.2 of [this paper](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/aistats/fullpapers/198.pdf) by Chapelle and Zien. They have a nice heuristic to select a good search range for $\sigma$ of the RBF kernel and $C$ for the SVM. I quote

> To determine good values of the remaining free parameters (eg, by CV),
>   it is important to search on the right scale. We therefore fix default
>   values for $C$ and $\sigma$ that have the right order of magnitude. In
>   a $c$-class problem we use the $1/c$ quantile of the pairwise
>   distances $D^\rho_{ij}$ of all data-points as a default for $\sigma$.
>   The default for $C$ is the inverses of the empirical variance $s^2$ in
>   features space, which can be calculated by $s^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i K_{ii} - \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j} K_{ij}$
>    from a $n\times n$ kernel
>   matrix $K$.

Afterwards, they use multiples (e.g. $2^k$ for $k\in \{-2,...,2\}$) of the default value as search range in a grid-search using cross-validation. That always worked very well for me.

Of course, we @ciri said, normalizing the data etc. is always a good idea.

Comment: I think there are several equal rbf kernel formulations. One with gamma and another with sigma, i.e. gamma = 1/2sigma^2. Does the gamma in the above heuristic correspond to gamma, sigma or sigma^2? I have found other descriptions of the same heurstic which are for gamma.

Comment: If you check the linked paper, it is $\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$

Comment: @fabee Should peer testing be done manually? there is not a library to achieve it?