# what is meant by "empirical variance in feature space"?

Tags: variance, svm, kernel-trick, hyperparameter, optimization

I was looking at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43943/which-search-range-for-determining-svm-optimal-c-and-gamma-parameters) to help determine a good range of values to grid search to optimize a support vector machine classifier.  In the second answer the poster links to [this paper](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/aistats/fullpapers/198.pdf) (section 2.3.2) in which they describe that a good default value for the Cost parameter  for an SVM is "the inverses of the empirical variance in feature space, which can be calculated by $s^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i K_{ii} - \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j} K_{ij}$ from an $n×n$ kernel matrix $K$. "

I'm not a mathematician, and I am really struggling to understand what exactly is symbolized in this equation. When they say "feature space" I assume they are talking about the matrix of features and their values for each case.  i.e. I have 10 features an 10 cases, so I have a 10x10 matrix in feature space.  Is that a correct interpretation?   I believe that the $\sum_i$ is a summation from $i$ to $n$ but I am not sure what is meant by the double subscript $i$ in  $K_{ii}$ or  $K_{i,j}$ .  Perhaps this has something to do with the kernel matrix that is used in SVM that I am not understanding.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same exact question here is what I found on this matter. I hope your up to date on your math theory http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/aistats/fullpapers/198.pdf