# hyperparameters optimisation with linear kernel

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, svm, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I want to conduct an SVM model-regression (i.e., support vector regression), using a **linear kernel function**. Does it make sense to perform a cross-validation hyperparameter optimization when the kernel function is linear? If so, what should be the range of values for each hyperparameter in the search?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes full sense to use cross-validation to find optimal hyper-parameters values in the case of SVM with a linear kernel.

If anything, the choosing the regularisation parameter $C$ in the Lagrange formulation is analogous to choosing the ridge regularisation parameter in ridge regression. Therefore it is necessary for our training data to be scaled appropriately (usually to mean $0$ and st.dev. $1$). Regarding the actual choice of the  $C$, it is generally common to use exponentially growing sequences of $C$; e.g.  $C = 2^{-6},2^{-5},\ldots,2^{5},2^{6}$, etc. CV.SE has a nice thread on this matter if one wants to explore this further: "[Which search range for determining SVM optimal C and gamma parameters?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43943/which-search-range-for-determining-svm-optimal-c-and-gamma-parameters)".

Answer (score 1):

As [usεr11852 says](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/453318/4598), cross validation does make sense for optimizing linear SVMs.

According to [Hastie *et al.*: The Entire Regularization Path for the Support Vector Machine, Journal of Machine Learning Research 5 (2004) 1391–1415](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume5/hastie04a/hastie04a.pdf), inside the cross validation you don't need to compute one SVM per C value as it is possible to compute the complete path of SVMs with varying Cs together.
If you work in R, package [svmpath](https://cran.r-project.org/package=svmpath) provides this.