# Understanding the different formulations for SVM

Tags: classification, svm, statistical-learning

I've been working with `kernlab` for more than a year now, but I always stickied to the vanilla cost (`C-svc`) formulation for classification.

Of course, `kernlab` includes some other formulations. In [the manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/kernlab.pdf), some classification formulations are briefly cited.
I'm quite familiar with *vanilla* Cost svms. For example, I know very well the `C-svc` and have a vague idea what encompasses a native multi-class formulation and I do understand the principles of `nu-svc`.

Could someone please shed some light on these different formulations and how they compare, if applicable, to `C-svc`? Information of different considerations made, robustness, sparseness, sensitivity to high dimensionality or class imbalances would be greatly useful.

- `C-svc`: C (Cost) classification
- `nu-svc`: $\nu$ (nSV) classification
- `C-bsvc`: bound-constraint SVM classification
- `spoc-svc` Crammer-Singer native multi-class
- `kbb-svc` Weston-Watkins native multi-class

Answer (score 8):

C-SVM:

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize}
&t(\mathbf w,b,\xi)=
{1\over2}\|\mathbf w\|_2^2+{C\over m}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\xi_i \\
&\text{subject to}
&\left\{\begin{matrix}
y_i(\langle\Phi(x_i),\mathbf w\rangle+b)\ge1-\xi_i &(\forall i=1,\dots,m)
\\ 
\xi_i \ge0
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}
$$

`C-svc` is the common SVM. The dual is:

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize}
&t(\alpha)=
{1\over2}\alpha^T\hat Q\alpha-\mathbf1^T \alpha\\
&\text{subject to}
&\left\{\begin{matrix}
y^t\alpha=0
\\ 
\mathbf 0\le \mathbf\alpha\le {C\over m}\mathbf1
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}
$$

With $\hat Q_{ij} \equiv y_iy_j \Phi(x_i)^T\Phi(x_j) $.

---

C-BSVM:

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize}
&t(\mathbf w,b,\xi)=
{1\over2}\|\mathbf w\|_2^2+{1\over2}b^2+{C\over m}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\xi_i \\
&\text{subject to}
&\left\{\begin{matrix}
y_i(\langle\Phi(x_i),\mathbf w\rangle+b)\ge1-\xi_i &(\forall i=1,\dots,m)
\\ 
\xi_i \ge0
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}
$$

`C-bsvc` introduces the offset $b$ in the objective. This simplifies the dual solution, with only bound constraints remaining.

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize}
&t(\alpha)=
{1\over2}\alpha^TQ\alpha-\mathbf1^T \alpha\\
&\text{subject to}
&\mathbf 0\le \mathbf\alpha\le {C\over m}\mathbf1
\end{align}
$$

With $Q_{ij} \equiv (y_iy_j \Phi(x_i)^T\Phi(x_j)+1) $

---

$\nu$-SVM:

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize}
&t(\mathbf w,b,\xi,\rho)=
{1\over2}\|\mathbf w\|_2^2-\nu\rho+{1\over m}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\xi_i \\
&\text{subject to}
&\left\{\begin{matrix}
y_i(\langle\Phi(x_i),\mathbf w\rangle+b)\ge\rho-\xi_i &(\forall i=1,\dots,m)
\\ 
\xi_i \ge0    & \rho\ge0
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}
$$

`nu-svc` has the following dual:

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize}
&t(\alpha)=
{1\over2}\alpha^T\hat Q\alpha\\
&\text{subject to}
&\left\{\begin{matrix}
y^t\alpha=0
\\ 
\mathbf 0\le \mathbf\alpha\le {1\over m}\mathbf1
\\
\|\alpha\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\ge \nu
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}
$$

This means that at least $\nu$ elements of the alpha vector will be non-zero. Or, in other words, $\nu$ is a lower bound on the fraction of support vectors.

---

<sub>[Karatzoglou, Alexandros, David Meyer, and Kurt Hornik. "Support vector machines in R." (2005).](https://escience.rpi.edu/data/DA/v15i09.pdf)</sub>

<sub>[Niu, Lingfeng, et al. "Two New Decomposition Algorithms for Training Bound-Constrained Support Vector Machines." Foundations of Computing and Decision Sciences 40.1 (2015): 67-86.](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/fcds.2015.40.issue-1/fcds-2015-0005/fcds-2015-0005.xml)</sub>