# Manually finding the bias term in classification SVM in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, e1071

Apropos of a follow-up question to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/260105/67822), I tried to prove to myself that I understood the notation in the [equation for the bias (page 5)](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58851af9ebbd1a30e98fb283/t/58902fbae4fcb5398aeb7505/1485844411772/SVM+Explained.pdf) in support vector machine SVM (classification, linear kernel), which is

$$b=\frac{1}{N_s}\sum_{s\in S}\left( y_s - \sum_{m\in S} \alpha_m\;y_m\;\mathbf x_m \cdot \mathbf x_s  \right)$$

corresponding (I believe) to the average across $N_s$ support vectors of the dot product of these vectors, i.e. $\mathbf x_m \cdot \mathbf x_s,$ scaled by the coefficients, $\alpha_m ,$ and classification values ($y_m=1$ or $y_m = - 1).$

---

As a toy example and reference point, I am using the example in [this post](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/svm/svm.html), summarized as

```
x1s <- c(.5,1,1,2,3,3.5,1,3.5,4,5,5.5,6)
x2s <- c(3.5,1,2.5,2,1,1.2,5.8,3,4,5,4,1)
ys <- c(rep(+1,6), rep(-1,6))
my.data <- data.frame(x1=x1s, x2=x2s, type=ys)

library(e1071)
svm.model <- svm(type ~ ., data=my.data, type='C-classification', kernel='linear',scale=FALSE)

# get parameters of hiperplane
w <- t(svm.model$coefs) %*% svm.model$SV
(b <- -svm.model$rho)
# [1] 5.365853
```

And we can prove that `svm.model$rho` is indeed the negative bias $b:$

Gathering together the support vectors with their labels and coefficients:

```
(sv = as.matrix(sapply(cbind(my.data[rownames(svm.model$SV),], coef = svm.model$coefs),as.numeric)))
#       x1  x2   type    coef
# [1,] 3.5 1.2    1    1.0000000
# [2,] 3.5 3.0   -1   -0.6487805
# [3,] 6.0 1.0   -1   -0.3512195
```

and remembering that the support vectors fulfill the equality

$$y_s\left(\mathbf w^\top \mathbf x_s + b\right)=1$$

as one of the constraints.

The bias, $\mathbf b,$ can calculated in the above example simply as:

```
-((sv[,"type"] * (svm.model$SV %*% t(w))) - matrix(rep(1,nrow(svm.model$SV)),,1))
        [,1]
6   5.390244
8  -5.365854
12 -5.365854
```

which is in fact equal to `rho  The negative intercept` as in the svm documentation.

---

In trying to reproduce `rho` (or $b$) with the initial formula this is what I have tried:

```
ind = numeric(3)
for (i in 1:3){
     ind[i] = sv[i,"type"] - sv[,"type"] %*% (sv[,"coef"] * (sv[,1:2] %*% sv[i,1:2]))
}
mean(ind)
# [1] -40.53398
```

which yields a result different from `rho` above (i.e. `svm.model$rho [1] -5.365853`.

> What am I doing wrong? Am I messing up the linear algebra, or misunderstanding the equation?

Answer (score 2):

There's a tiny mistake in your loop.

From [e1071 documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf):

> `coefs` The corresponding coefficients times the training labels.

It means `coefs` = $\alpha_S \odot y_S$ or, for a specific index, `coefs[m]` = $\alpha_m y_m$

When you compute this line

```
ind[i] = sv[i,"type"] - sv[,"type"] %*% (sv[,"coef"] * (sv[,1:2] %*% sv[i,1:2]))
```

it's the same as

```
ind[i] = sv[i,'type'] - sum(sv[,'coef'] * sv[,'type'] * sv[,1:2] %*% sv[i,1:2])
```

and, assuming $X_S = \{\mathbf{x}_i | i \in S\}$ is composed of column vectors, it corresponds to the following formulas (notice the extra $y_m$ inside the innermost sum)
$$
y_s - \mathbf{y}_S \cdot \left (\mathbf{\alpha}_S \odot \mathbf{y}_S \odot X_S^T\mathbf{x}_s\right )
=\\
y_s - \sum_{m \in S} \alpha_m y_m y_m \langle \mathbf{x}_m,\mathbf{x}_s \rangle
\\
$$

---

So to reproduce this formula

$$
y_s - \sum_{m \in S} \alpha_m y_m \langle \mathbf{x}_m,\mathbf{x}_s \rangle
$$

use the line below inside the loop

```
ind[i] = sv[i,'type'] - sum(sv[,'coef'] * sv[,1:2] %*% sv[i,1:2])
```

Wrapping up, the correct loop is

```
ind = numeric(3)
for(i in 1:3) {
    ind[i] = sv[i,'type'] - sum(sv[,'coef'] * sv[,1:2] %*% sv[i,1:2])
}
```

And the result it yields is the same you obtained when computed the biases for the constraints $y_s(\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_s +b) = 1$.

```
> ind
# [1] 5.390244 5.365854 5.365854

> mean(ind)
# [1] 5.373984
```

Just a note here that in your example you should divide by $y_s$ again, to obtain
$$b = \frac{y_s \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_s - 1}{-y_s}$$

```
> bias = -((sv[,"type"] * (svm.model$SV %*% t(w))) -1)/sv[,'type']
#        [,1]
# 6  5.390244
# 8  5.365854
# 12 5.365854

> bias
# [1] 5.390244 5.365854 5.365854

> mean(bias)
# [1] 5.373984
```

---

TL;DR: remove the `sv[,'type']`

Comment: Just a quick and mindless check with the replacement you indicate yields 5.373984 as opposed to 5.390244. Would you mind including the entire code chunk in your response?

Comment: Sorry, I should've added it. Yes, the answer you should get with this line is the same as when you computed the bias for the equality constraints.

Comment: I see you have the answer, but I still don't get why we get that 5.390244, or the mean 5.373984, when `(b <- -svm.model$rho) # [1] 5.365853`.

Comment: I thought it could be numerical error at first or that the constraint related to the first support vector had some slack value there yet, because in the original formulation the constraints are inequalities, however as it's a margin maximization problem it wouldn't make sense to have different distances between the support vectors and the separating hyperplane. Anyway I should check the formulation and get back to you.

Comment: @AntoniParellada I took a look at the dual formulation and as cost=1 is the default C value in e1071's svm, the constraints $0 \leq \alpha_i \leq C, \forall i$ and $\sum_i \alpha_i y_i = 0$ get a little too restrictive and one of the alphas (associated to the only support vector of the positive class) can't grow larger than 1. Executing with a larger cost you allow it to eventually get to ~1.01 and you'll see that $\langle \mathbf{w},\mathbf{x} \rangle +b $ will yield $-1$ or $+1$ for every support vector (instead of ~.98 for one of them, in this case).

Comment: If you want I could add it to the original answer and plot both margins (with different C values) so you could see that one of them moves a little with this change.