# support vector machines - margin

Tags: svm

Support vector machines always show a margin whose width changes. How can I find what my margin is ? Eg, if my weights are $[-1,1]$ what is my margin ? Also, do larger weights mean larger margin ?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen the general discussion of SVMs at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23391/how-does-a-support-vector-machine-svm-work?  Perhaps that will help.  Otherwise, search our site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsvm%5D+margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Larger weights mean smaller margin. Given the weights you can compute the margin by 1/||w||.

Comment: thank you whuber and saibot. It was a matter of plugging in some values and vizualization.